# FullCalendar5 - exdate property is being ignored

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a rrule for a repeating event starting at Sep 1, 2021 until June 1, 2022. The date Sep 21, 2021 should be excluded, but in fact it still remains there.

[image]

How do I solve it?

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { BreadcrumbService } from '@core/services';
import {
  CalendarOptions,
  DateSelectArg,
  EventClickArg,
  EventApi,
  FullCalendarComponent
} from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { Draggable, DropArg } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import bgLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/bg';
import { ConfirmationService, MenuItem, MessageService, SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-schedule',
  templateUrl: './add-schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-schedule.component.scss']
})
export class AddScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MenuItem[];
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions;
  currentEvents: EventApi[];

  educationForm: SelectItem[];
  selectedEducationForm: SelectItem;

  subjectType: SelectItem[];

  eventDialog: boolean;
  clickedEvent: EventApi;
  changedEvent: any;

  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;

  constructor(
    private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private confirmationService: ConfirmationService
  ) {
    this.breadcrumbService.setItems([{ label: 'Разпис' }, { label: 'Създаване' }]);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changedEvent = { title: '', start: null, end: null, subject: '', room: '', lecturer: '', subjectType: '' };

    this.calendarOptions = {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today'
      },
      titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' },
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      events: [
        {
          id: '1',
          title: 'event 1',
          // startRecur: '2021-09-01',
          // endRecur: '2022-06-01',
          // startTime: '07:00:00',
          // endTime: '08:00:00',
          // daysOfWeek: ['2', '4'],
          extendedProps: {
            subject: 'Математика',
            room: '414',
            lecturer: 'Ванката',
            subjectType: 'Семинарно упражнение'
          },
          rrule: {
            freq: 'weekly',
            interval: 1, // every one week
            byweekday: [ 'tu', 'th' ],
            dtstart: '2021-09-01T07:00:00',
            until: '2022-06-01'
          },
          exdate: ['2021-09-21'],
          duration: '03:00:00'
        }
      ],
      slotMinTime: '06:00:00',
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      slotLabelFormat: [
        {
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: '2-digit',
          omitZeroMinute: false,
          meridiem: 'short'
        }
      ],
      locale: bgLocale,
      firstDay: 1,
      allDaySlot: false,
      weekends: true,
      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      droppable: true,
      expandRows: true,
      stickyHeaderDates: true,
      contentHeight: 'auto', // remove scrollbar
      eventOverlap: false, // no events overlap
      selectOverlap: false, // no events overlap
      nowIndicator: true,

      select: (selectInfo: DateSelectArg) => {
        const title = prompt('Event Title:');
        const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

        calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

        if (title) {
          calendarApi.addEvent({
            title: title,
            start: selectInfo.start,
            end: selectInfo.end
          });
        }
      },
      drop: (drop: DropArg) => {
        if ((document.getElementById('drop-remove') as HTMLInputElement).checked) {
          drop.draggedEl.parentNode?.removeChild(drop.draggedEl);
        }
      },
      eventClick: (clickInfo: EventClickArg) => {
        this.eventDialog = true;

        this.clickedEvent = clickInfo.event;

        this.changedEvent.id = this.clickedEvent.id;
        this.changedEvent.title = this.clickedEvent.title;
        this.changedEvent.start = this.clickedEvent.start;
        this.changedEvent.end = this.clickedEvent.end;
        this.changedEvent.subject = this.clickedEvent.extendedProps['subject'];
        this.changedEvent.room = this.clickedEvent.extendedProps['room'];
        this.changedEvent.lecturer = this.clickedEvent.extendedProps['lecturer'];
        this.changedEvent.subjectType = this.clickedEvent.extendedProps['subjectType'];

        // if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
        //   clickInfo.event.remove();
        // }
      },
      eventsSet: (events: EventApi[]) => {
        this.currentEvents = events;
      }
    };

    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'New',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus'
      },
      {
        label: 'Edit',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil'
      },
      {
        label: 'Delete',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of fullCalendar do you have, precisely? `exdate` only works from 5.5 onwards.

Comment: @ADyson, `"@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/rrule": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.9.0",`

Comment: Ok thanks. I wonder then if it's a mismatch between the date/time in the exdate and the date/time in the event. I don't know for sure, but can you try with `exdate: ['2021-09-21T07:00']` - the intention is that it excludes that specific timeslot. If that's not right then I would have to think about it some more and make a test case.

Comment: @ADyson, hmm, you are right, it worked that way. It's strange because they stated in the docs that it should work the other way too. Thank you very much and would you like to write it as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've posted as an answer, below. FWIW I've just re-read the documentation and I don't think it specifically states that it behaves in the way you expected. I would argue though that it's perhaps a bit vague about exactly how it will behave, and could be made more useful and detailed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mismatch between the date/time in the exdate and the date/time in the event. You need to write:

```
exdate: ['2021-09-21T07:00']
```

to match the time in the `dtstart` property of the RRule. It will then exclude items which occur at that specific timeslot. If you only specify the date, then it only looks for "all-day" events to exclude, it does not account for everything occurring within that day. I didn't write the code or specification for this obviously, but it's possible to imagine a scenario where you want to exclude certain all-day events on specific days, but still show timed events. I would imagine the intention with this behaviour was to account for that scenario.

More info about the RRule fullCalendar plugin, including info on exclusion dates, can be found at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

Comment: Thank you once again!