# Fullcalendar RRule exdate/exrule is not excluding date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, rrule

When I try to add an exception to my recurring fullcalendar event, it is not doing anything. The recurring event is displayed correctly each week, but without any exception.

What I am trying to achieve is to show a series of events, with the exclusion of a certain date or even better a range between dates and times, like described here in the part "Exclusion Properties": https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

This is my event:

```
events: [
                {
                  id: '291',
                  resourceId: '29',
                  color: '#71CA83',
                  textColor: '#ffffff',
                  description: 'Manager1 Manager1 : 08:00:00 - 10:30:00',
                  rrule: {
                    freq: 'weekly',
                    interval: 1,
                    byweekday: 'rrule.RRule.MO',
                    dtstart: '2021-03-01T08:00:00'
                  },
                  duration: '02:00',
                  exdate: ['2021-10-11'] 
                }
]
```

I am using fullcalendar 5.9.0 (with a commercial license) and rrule 2.6.8. Also good to mention: I am running a Macbook with MacOS Big Sur.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? I have tried multiple solutions and read a lot of documentation, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `I am using fullcalendar 2.9.0`... but if you look, the rrule integration was not introduced until version 4 and exdate not until version 5.5. the version 2 documentation doesn't have any mention of rrule

Comment: I am sorry, I use 5.9.0

Comment: Ah ok. In that case it's almost certainly the same problem as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258139/fullcalendar5-exdate-property-is-being-ignored/

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to solve my problem. I tried this solution both with and without brackets, but the events stays...

Comment: The answer I showed you has nothing to do with brackets - I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion? It's all about the absence of a time from your exdate setting

Comment: I know that...I tried this: exdate: ['2021-10-12T07:00'] both with and without brackets

Comment: Since your `dtstart` contains `08:00` not `07:00` that might be the reason?

Comment: If we correct that typo then it looks like there is no issue - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWvKgzY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the time to exclude in your `exdate` as well, otherwise it won't match to the specific timeslot mentioned in the `dstart` setting.

```
exdate: ['2021-10-11T08:00']
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWvKgzY

If you only specify the date in `exdate`, then it only looks for "all-day" events to exclude, it does not account for everything occurring within that day. I didn't write the code or specification for this obviously, but it's possible to imagine a scenario where you want to exclude certain all-day events on specific days, but still show timed events. I would imagine the intention with this behaviour was to account for that scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the codepen example, this is really helpful. I think my problem is occuring because I am using the resources timeline view. Will investigate some more.

Comment: No, you'd have the same issue in any of the views. The type of view you're using is independent of whether fullCalendar decides to exclude the event from the list or not. Does the answer not solve your problem? It should.

Comment: I changed the demo so it shows all the different view types. My exclusion rule works the same in them all (you can just refresh the same link to see the update). If you're having an issue, make sure you've changed the exdate time from 07:00 to 08:00 as per my example.

Comment: Thank you very much! This gave much more insight. I now see that the exdate time has to match the dtstart time exactly to work. This also means that a partial exclusion will probably not be possible unfortunately. I was trying To achieve a work schedule for multiple workers in which they could include their normal work times and exclude their holiday times which can sometimes be half a day. But this does not seem to work with the exdate function. I will look into exrule to see if I can achieve this with that function - or if you have an idea, please let me know

Comment: I don't see why you can't set the exdate rule programmatically, if you know whether the excluded event is a half or full day (which you do, because you obviously hold the event data). What are you seeing as the barrier to that?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is something like this example: an event weekly on mondays from 9:00-17:00, but sometimes an exclusion of 11:00-13:00. If you program an exclusion with a starttime from 9:00 it works, but it removes the event as a whole. I would like to see the event partially removed.

Comment: You can't do that. It can only exclude events, not parts of events. You would need to split the event up into its component parts, so you end up with two events: 0900-1100 and 1300-1700. fullCalendar and rrule have no concept of a portion of an event, only the whole event.

Comment: So if you're aiming to allow users to specify such exclusions to their overall working pattern, you'd have to create a UI where they can specify the exclusion period, and then use that to go into the database (or whatever) where you store the events, and maybe a) add an exdate to exclude the main event for the date in question, and then b) create new standalone event(s) specifically for that day, to cover the period which is still going to be worked. That would work for the case you've just described, at any rate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Too bad this is not possible. My temporary solution is to show the time "off" next to the normal time schedule for each team member

Comment: That's true, you can simply make another event for the time off which will then be displayed on top of the bigger one by fullCalendar. That might be the simplest solution.